# Random variable, confusion from theoretical to practical

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

From theoretical perspective, we define $X$ is a real-valued random variable from $(\Omega, \mathcal{A})$ to $(\Bbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\Bbb{R}))$ iff it is a measurable function wrt to $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}(\Bbb{R})$. To calculate the probability of events in $\mathcal{A}$, we add a measure $P$ on $(\Omega, \mathcal{A})$, and through $P$, we can define the law $P_X$ of $X$ as the image measure induced by $X$.

In practical setting, we always skip some details and focus on the property of specific random variables.

What I know is if we have $(E, \mathcal{E}, \mu)$, we can always choose $(\Omega, \mathcal{A},\nu)=(E, \mathcal{E}, \mu)$, so the identity function as a random variable satisfying the law $\mu$.

> My question is When we say a Bernoulli random variable, $P(X=0)=p, P(X=1)=1-p$, does it mean we give the law of this random variable? Here it seems we only consider the target space $=(\{0,1\}, 2^{\{0,1\}}, P)$, Is it a real-valued random variable? Why it is measurable wrt $\mathcal{B}(\Bbb{R})$? What is $P(U)$, where $U$ is other borel set of $\Bbb{R}$? Why there exists a measurable function from some $(\Omega, \mathcal{A})$ to $(\Bbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\Bbb{R}))$ such that induced $P_X=P$?

Same question for the continuous random variable? Can you give me for example, the analogous answer for normal random variable?

Comment: Not important for your question, but we usually say for a Bernoulli random variable that $P(X=1)=p, P(X=0)=1-p$.  Either way round, it is real-valued since $\{0,1\}\subset \mathbb R$ and  $\{0,1\}\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: 1) Your first sentence is already wrong. That would be called a measurable function. What differentiates a random variable from a measurable function is that $\Omega$ a priori has a probability measure associated with it, and not a posteriori as your description suggests. 2) It is perfectly fine, for the scenarios you are mentioning, to identify random variables with their law. In your example with the Bernoullis, just take $X:(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R),p\delta_{\{1\}}+(1-p)\delta_{\{0\}}) \to (\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ to be the identity map.

Comment: You can say my first point is just semantics or blah blah, but really the point is that we identify these such measurable functions with their law. On the other hand, outside of probability, one is actually concerned with what the particular function is and its regularity properties.

Answer (score 2):

A Bernoulli random variable is a random variable $X$ defined on some probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F, P)$ such that $P[\omega\in\Omega: X(\omega)\in\{0,1\}]=1$. (The default meaning of "random variable" is "measurable map from $(\Omega,\mathcal F)$ to $(\Bbb R,\mathcal B(\Bbb R))$.)

The label "Bernoulli" refers to the nature of the image distribution, not to $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$.

Given $X$ as above we can modify it slightly by defining $Y(\omega)=X(\omega)$ if $X(\omega)\in\{0,1\}$ and $Y(\omega)=0$ (say) if $X(\omega)\in\Bbb R\setminus \{0,1\}$. Then $Y$ is a random variable with range contained in $\{0,1\}$, and $P(Y=X)=1$. In particular, $Y$ is also a Bernoulli random variable, with $p:=P(Y=1)=P(X=1)$.

You can check that a function $X:\Omega\to \{0,1\}$ is a random variable (i.e. $X^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal F$ for all $B\in\mathcal B(\Bbb R)$ if and only if $\{X=1\}\in\mathcal F$.